# SolveFactory('gams'): modify OPTCA and OPTCR

Tags: python, pyomo

When invoking gams solver in pyomo as follows

SolverFactory('gams').solve(model,  solver = 'CONOPT', tee = True)

is it possible to modify the solver options OPTCR and OPTCA ?

Thanks in advance for your time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use the `add_options` parameter to insert arbitrary lines:

```
SolverFactory('gams').solve(model, solver='baron', tee=True, add_options=['option optcr=0.001;', 'option optca=0.01;'])
```

Comment: Thank you Qi! I really appreciate your help ! It works !

Comment: You're quite welcome. Btw, it is customary if a solution works to mark the answer as "Accepted" on StackOverflow.